# How can I get rid of indestructible creatures with a Red and White deck?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander, mtg-indestructible

I am creating a Red-White commander deck using [Gisela](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=240034) as my commander.  I noticed that my deck is incredibly weak against a deck with any sort of indestructible creature.  I know of the board sweeper [Terminus](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=262703), but I was wondering if red/white has any other tricks up its sleeve to get rid of tricky creatures.  I'm looking for both sweepers and target-specific cards.

Comment: Rolling back the title. This isn't our canon question on removing indestructible creatures as it and its answers are - and always have been - focused on red and white. Changing the title doesn't change that, nor is it appropriate as it's significantly changing the meaning of the question. If there is to be a canon question about removing indestructible creatures for any and all colours, that needs to be asked in a new question. This question does convey typically helpful information, but that information can just resurface in the canon question.

Comment: @doppelgreener Agreed - the edited title didn't even match the body of the question, let alone the original intent or the answers. If the idea was to turn it into a generic question, it wasn't even a good attempt at it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are a variety of general answers for indestructible permanents:

1. Exile effects, which are your real bread-and-butter for all kinds of removal.
2. Toughness-reducing effects against creatures.
3. Sacrifice effects.
4. "Tuck" (move to library) effects.
5. Bouncing permanents (temporary).
6. Stealing permanents: the indestructible thing isn't a problem if you control it, right?
7. Ability- and action- restricting cards like [Pithing Needle](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPithing%20Needle%5d) and [Pacifism](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPacifism%5d), if all you're worried about is disabling a card rather than removing it from the battlefield.

---

White is probably the strongest color for dealing with indestructible permanents after they've resolved. Some of your options are:

- [Oblivion Ring](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bOblivion%20Ring%5d) and [similar enchantments](https://scryfall.com/search?q=t%3Aenchantment%20commander%3Awr%20o%3Aexile%20o%3Apermanent%20o%3Aleaves&unique=cards&as=grid&order=name) provide single-shot answers to any non-land permanent. Note, in particular, [Grasp of Fate](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGrasp%20of%20Fate%5d) as the multiplayer-oriented variant.
- [Path to Exile](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPath%20to%20Exile%5d) and [Swords to Plowshares](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSwords%20to%20Plowshares%5d) are low-cost instant answers for creatures.
- [Return to Dust](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bReturn%20to%20Dust%5d) for is a nice two-for-one against artifacts and enchantments.
- [Final Judgement](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFinal%20Judgement%5d), [Descend Upon the Sinful](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDescend%20Upon%20the%20Sinful%5d), and [False Prophet](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFalse%20Prophet%5d) are an exile-based sweeper.
- [Hallowed Burial](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHallowed%20Burial%5d) and [Terminus](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTerminus%5d) are "tuck"-based sweepers.
- [Condemn](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCondemn%5d) can "tuck" a troublesome creature, although only when it's attacking.
- [Pacifism](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPacifism%5d) effects may be good enough if you're just trying to get rid of a blocker or prevent a card from using its activated abilities; [Faith's Fetters](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFaith%27s%5d%2b%5bFetters%5d) and [Prison Term](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPrison%20Term%5d) are probably the best choice there.
- [Angel of the Dire Hour](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAngel%20of%20the%20Dire%20Hour%5d) can wipe out a wave of indestructible attackers.
- [Elesh Norn](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bElesh%20Norn%5d) will clear out a lot of weenies even if they're indestructible.
- [Evangelize](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEvangelize%5d) and a *lot* mana: steal all their stuff.
- [Gideon, Champion of Justice](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGideon%2c%20Champion%20of%20Justice%5d) will exile everything else on the battlefield.
- [Oblation](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bOblation%5d) "tucks" any nonland permanent at the cost of giving your opponent more cards.

In red:

- [Chaos Warp](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bChaos%20Warp%5d) can "tuck" anything.
- [Into the Core](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bInto%20the%20Core%5d) can answer indestructible artifacts like [Darksteel Forge](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDarksteel%20Forge%5d).
- [Apocalypse](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bApocalypse%5d) and [Decree of Annihilation](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDecree%20of%20Annihilation%5d) are exile-based sweepers.
- [Warp World](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWarp%20World%5d) and similar cards will remove the offending permanents, at the cost of giving your opponent new toys to replace them.
- [Insurrection](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bInsurrection%5d) will let you take all of an opponent's creatures for a turn — usually that's enough to finish off a player or feed them all to a sacrifice outlet like [Ashnod's Altar](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAshnod%27s%5d%2b%5bAltar%5d) so you don't have to give them back.

Colorless cards worth noting:

- [Duplicant](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDuplicant%5d) is a popular card for exiling creatures.
- [Brittle Effigy](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBrittle%20Effigy%5d), [Amulet of Unmaking](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAmulet%20of%20Unmaking%5d), and [Helvault](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHelvault%5d) provide targeted exile effects, though not very cost-effectively compared to what you can get in white.
- [Karn Liberated](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKarn%20Liberated%5d) and [Ugin, the Spirit Dragon](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUgin%2c%20the%20Spirit%20Dragon%5d) can easily exile multiple troublesome permanents.
- [All Is Dust](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAll%20Is%20Dust%5d) is a sacrifice-based sweeper.

Comment: Don't forget Faith's Fetters in there with Pacifism! :)

Comment: Excellent list! Oblation is another one I'd include, with similar power and utility to Chaos Warp.

Answer (score 4):

[Apocalypse](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bApocalypse%5d) , [Path to Exile](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPath%20to%20Exile%5d), [Swords to Plowshares](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSwords%20to%20Plowshares%5d), [Crib Swap](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCrib%20Swap%5d), [Parallax Wave](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bParallax%20Wave%5d), [Archon of Justice](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bArchon%20of%20Justice%5d), [Witch Hunter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWitch%20Hunter%5d), [Evangelize](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEvangelize%5d), [Helm of Possession](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHelm%20of%20Possession%5d), [Preacher](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPreacher%5d), [Tariff](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTariff%5d), [Warp World](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWarp%20World%5d), ...

The most effective answer is to learn to use the Gatherers Advanced Search to search for keywords in the rules **sacrifice, exile, gain control**, then exclude cards that are not **red, white, or colorless***. You will get some false positives, but it is a start.

Like so: [Color=NOT(B|U|G) AND Text=Exile+Target+Creature](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?page=1&action=advanced&color=+!%5BB%5D+!%5BU%5D+!%5BG%5D&text=+%5BExile%5D+%5Btarget%5D+%5Bcreature%5D)

Like so: [Color=NOT(B|U|G) AND Text=Sacrifices+Target+Creature](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&color=+!%5BB%5D+!%5BU%5D+!%5BG%5D&text=+%5BSacrifices%5D+%5Btarget%5D+%5Bcreature%5D)

Like so: [Color=NOT(B|U|G) AND Text="Gain Control of Target Creature"](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&color=+!%5BB%5D+!%5BU%5D+!%5BG%5D&text=+%5B%22Gain%20control%20of%20target%20creature%22%5D)

Comment: @shujaa, I actually added the searches. I thought I did it originally, but was having issues with creating multiple (OR x,y,z) AND (OR a,b,c). It might be the case that Gatherer doesn't support that sort of search/syntax (or I just suck)

Answer (score 2):

Although toughness reduction is not particularly white or red (which does gets +*/-* effects, though), you could look at creatures with Wither or Infect. In control-stealing, red has many temporary stealing spells and effects with stuff like Act of Treason, Blind with Anger, Grab the Reins, Mark of Mutiny, Threaten, Tibalt, Traitorous Blood, Zealous Conscripts... White has the non-time limited Preacher, though.

Answer (score 1):

The answers here were all correct at the time, but there have been new cards printed that I believe are worth adding. Three newer cards specifically remove the ability indestructible, they are:

- [Burn from Within](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBurn%20from%20Within%5d)
- [Hour of Devastation](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHour%20of%20Devastation%5d)
- [Bonds of Mortality](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBonds%20of%20Mortality%5d)

The first two are playable in your Boros deck, the third being green is not, but all three specifically remove indestructible.